# Signing AuthenRequest SAML

Tags: request, saml, signing, x509certificate2

I am trying to sign my HTTP-Redirect binding AuthenRequest so I can send it to the Idp. What is the logic behind signing the request? Do I sign it using my x509 and a private key? Do I sign it using my private key and Idp's x509 cert? Also, the Idp requires the signature query parameter. Do I simply extract the signature value from the request after I sign it?

I am developing in c# .net

Thanks

Comment: Signing redirect binding is a pain, and isn't required by spec for AuthnRequest. I would make sure that your IdP absolutely requires it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I know it's a pain. However, the Idp requires it. Do you have a known solution on how to do it?

Comment: What framework/SAML mechanism are you using?

Comment: I hope I properly answer your question. I am using SAML2 HTTP-Redirect. I am not using any third party software or services however, I am using a ComponentPro SAML library. I asked them for this solution and no reply from them. My query string parameters are:
?SAMLRequest=" + encodedAuthnRequest
                        + "&SigAlg=" + shaParameterInfo
                        + "&Signature=" + b64encodedSig
                        + "&RelayState=" + ssohelper.CompressBase64("VOLOSSO").ToString();

The problem is with my Signature algorithm (SHA1).

Comment: @yura FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest solution to get the proper Signature value in HTTP-Redirect post is to use a 3rd party library for c# called ComponentPro. Below is what I used to get it to work:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = RedirectUtil.CreateQueryString("SAMLRequest", authnRequest.GetXml(), relayState, key, signatureAlgorithm);
```

The key is the private key.

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY

Answer (score 2):

You always sign with your private key. The recipient will verify the signature using your public key.

In this case, you sign the SAML authn request with your private key and the identity provider will verify the signature with your public key.

Typically you supply the identity provider with your public key as a certificate file or as part of your SAML metadata.

If the IdP requires the signature as part of the query string, this means they want you to use the HTTP-Redirect binding to send the authn request. You need to look at the SAML v2.0 bindings specification to understand how to implement this. The signature is not part of the request and therefore isn't extracted from it.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure out that the Signature query string is Signature = urlencode( base64 ( SigAlg ("SAMLRequest=value&RelayState=value&SigAlg=value"))) however, I can't seem to find the SHA1 signing algorithm sample code in c#.